# Update Opportunity on Save

Tags: apex, visualforce, opportunity, update

I have a visualforce page with input fields that default to the current value of the opportunity. When I click save I want it to update the opportunity and then redirect to a new page. I have the button working where it will act like it is updating the opportunity and then redirect, but when I go look at the opportunity values they remain unchanged. Any ideas? here's the code:

VisualForce:

```
<apex:page controller="ContractDetails"  showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <apex:slds />
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <apex:form id="wf">
    <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_edit  slds-hint-parent " style="max-width:15%">
        <center><span class="slds-form-element__label slds-no-space" >August</span>
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">

                <apex:inputfield value="{!ThisOpportunity.Usage_Aug__c}" style="max-width:100%; height:1.875rem;font-size:12px;background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);color: rgb(22, 50, 92);border: 1px solid rgb(216, 221, 230);border-radius: .25rem;transition: border .1s linear,background-color .1s linear;padding: 0 1rem 0 .75rem;" />

            </div></center>
    </div>
    <apex:actionfunction action="{!done}" name="doneupdate" rerender="wf"></apex:actionfunction>
    </apex:form>
    <footer class="slds-p-around_small">

            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-center">
                <input type="button" class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" Value="Cancel"/>
                <input type="button" class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="doneupdate()" value="Save"/>

            </div>
    </footer>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class ContractDetails{

    public Opportunity ThisOpportunity{get;set;} 
    public string oppid {get;set;}
    public ContractDetails(){
        ThisOpportunity = [Select Usage_Aug__c FROM Opportunity where ID=:oppid];
    }
    public PageReference done(){
        update ThisOpportunity;
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/ContractDetails');
        pg.getParameters().put('oppidd', oppid);
        pg.setRedirect(true);   
        return pg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try selecting the `Id` in the query `[Select Id, Usage_Aug__c FROM Opportunity where ID=:oppid]`;

Comment: this is a segmented query.. I have a bunch of other fields selected including ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly redirect from `save` function itself.

```
public PageReference done(){
    update ThisOpportunity;
    PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/ContractDetails');
    returnPage.getParameters().put('oppidd', oppid);
    returnPage.setRedirect(true);       
}
```

Secondly, when you use `actionFunction` be sure to use `rerender` attribute.

```
<input type="button" class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="doneupdate()" value="Save"/>
<apex:actionfunction action="{!done}" name="doneupdate" rerender="form1">
</apex:actionfunction>
```

**Update**

`inputField` is outside of the form which you are submitting. so declare single `apex:form` after `apex:page` and add all fields and buttons in that form.

Comment: I made those changes and it works for the redirect, so thank you for correcting that. But the update still isn't taking the inputfield values.

Comment: `inputField` is outside of the form which you are submitting. so declare single `apex:form` after `apex:page`. updated my ans

Comment: If I place the apex:actionfunction inside the form and keep the button in the footer, it actually works as well.

Comment: then whats the use for apex:form? if you put button in footer means outside of form.

Comment: floats with the scrolling

Comment: you are making simple things to the complicated one. You can raise a separate questions for any other issues

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figured out how to make it float without using footer